# Setting the length for when ~P wrapps the text in erlang

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to make erlang print the full string even if one has used  `~P` in a `io:format` function?

Im having some troubles with EDoc and it keeps wrapping the error messages to `...`.

Is there any flags or other way to force erlang to print the entire string?

Comment: I take it you'd like to do this without modifying the (EDoc) source code?

Answer (score 0):

The only method I have found is to use `io_lib:print(Term, Column, LineLength, Depth)`. That function allows you to specify the starting column, the line length to control wrapping, etc. It returns a string which you can then print using `io:format` with `~s` format.